# Referencing current cell for compare across sheets

Tags: excel, compare, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to compare binary values between two sheets in Excel.  Here's a quick snapshot of what the data might look like for row 1, columns A-D on the two sheets.

```
    A  B  C  D
1   1  1  1  1  <--- Sheet 1

    A  B  C  D
1   1  1  0  0  <--- Sheet 2
```

What I would like to do is Conditionally Format sheet 2.  I'm only concerned about the cells where the values are not the same, so in the example above cells C1 and D1 on Sheet 2 do not match the values on Sheet 1, so I want to either change the font or background.  At this point I don't care.  If I were just comparing these 4 cells I could do this easily enough.  But I've actually got 160 rows and about 1000 columns of binary data, so I don't want to condition each cell individually.  What I can't figure out is how to conditionally format the entire sheet using a formula that references the current cell vs the current cell on the other sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For excel 2010:

1. Select the area on sheet 2 you want to compare
2. Select conditional formatting under the "home" ribbon, then "new rule"
3. Select "use a formula to determine which cells to format"
4. Type the following, but replace "A1" with the top left cell in your selection range, and replace the sheet names with your sheet names

> **=IF(Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A1,FALSE,TRUE)**
>
> Select your desired format
>
> Hit "OK" on both dialogs

Comment: Two points to note, the above solution will only work in Excel 2010 and above, you previously couldn't, directly, have conditional formatting across worksheets,. Also =NOT(Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A1)) would be a probably be a little more efficient

Answer (score 0):

In general, you could use a comparison utility like BeyondCompare.  Ensure each sheet is saved into its own file, then throw them at the utility.